Насколько логично такое утверждение (о нормах языка)
Как устанавливаются языковые нормы?  Вероятно, здесь прежде всего ориентируются на существующую речевую практику. Язык — это живой организм, и он меняется по своим законам, им нельзя управлять по своему желанию.
Но вот ответ Справочной службы:
Огромное число носителей языка убеждены, что названия типа Строгино, 
Останкино, Алтуфьево не склоняются, но это не так. 

Насколько логично такое утверждение?  Можно ли не принимать во внимание мнение "огромного числа носителей языка"?
А это вся тема:
Я живу в СЗАО, в районе Строгино. Давным-давно 
привыкла склонять это имя собственное. Кроме меня 
этого не делает никто абсолютно, смеются, говорят, 
что это глупость. Я человек грамотный, да и 
образование у меня лингвистическое. Скажите, 
пожалуйста, ведь я права?
ОТВЕТ
Конечно, Вы правы. Огромное число носителей языка 
убеждены, что названия типа Строгино, Останкино, 
Алтуфьево не склоняются, но это не так. 

Я тоже смеюсь. И над теми,  кто говорит в Строгине, и над странным утверждением Грамоты. Как у нас любят "цепляться" за старые нормы, как хочется сохранить свою исключительную "лингвистическую грамотность"!
Если ударение падает на окончание, но склоняемые форма (в Строгине, в Люблине) выглядит совершенно неприемлемо (из-за смягчения согласного перед окончанием Е).
